# MS SQL - AT TIME ZONE and DST - Wrong usage?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a piece of code like this:

```
Cast('2017-09-02 00:00:00' as datetime)  AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time'
```

Output:

**2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 +02:00**

However, Central Europe Standard Time currently has an offset of *+01:00*. So i would expect this output:

**2017-09-02 00:00:00.000 +01:00**

Am I using AT TIME ZONE incorrectly?

Comment: `currently has an offset of +01:00` but what about during the date you are querying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It converts related to the date, not when it is executed

on 2nd of September it is still DST so +02:00 is correct

if you do:

```
Cast('2017-12-02 00:00:00' as datetime)  AT TIME ZONE 'Central Europe Standard Time'
```

it will be +01:00 as 2nd of december does not have DST

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely right. This makes the output absolutely sensible. Thanks.